# Load python modules and path them variable attributes

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder

```
    /
        alphabet/
            __init__.py
            a.py
            b.py
            ...
    main.py
```

The modules in `alphabet/` have to be unknown to me, and I want to access them when importing from main.py, so this is what `alphabet/__init__.py` looks like

```
from os import listdir, path

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('alphabet') if path.isfile(path.join("alphabet", f))]
__all__ = [f[:-3] for f in onlyfiles if f != '__init__.py' and f[-2:] == "py"]
```

And that how `main.py` calls them

```
import alphabet
modules = [l for l in alphabet.__all__]
print(modules)
```

`["a", "b", ...]`

Now I want to run a function named `sound()` from `a.py`

```
for m in modules:
    alphabet.m.sound()
```

But it gives this error `AttributeError: module 'alphabet' has no attribute 'm'`

Comment: is it working directly when used like alphabet.a.sound()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier solution in which I use `eval()`

```
for m in modules:
    eval('alphabet.{}.sound()'.format(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with this it's difficult to begin. You can reference the following to begin debugging your application:

In your `for` loop, you cannot use the variable m in a dotted notation, as the interpreter will try to access the literal `m` module and not the variable name. A valid way to try that would be to call `alphabet.__all__[m].sound()`. But it won't actually work since you never imported that part of the code. The correct way is to use the `importlib` module and load submodules on the fly, something like

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('alphabet.a')
```

How you build the function attribute for `import_module` is up to you.
Furthermore putting the submodule names in `__all__` only exposes them to the importer (or hides them) and doesn't actually import them at runtime. You have to use `import * from alphabet` to import all the submodules in `__all__`.

I would strongly recommend you research package development for python and return to this.